# Timer reset when it hits 24 hours and how to show minutes and hours on the timer swift

Tags: swift, timer, reset

I am creating a timer app and i want the timer to reset itself when it hits 24 hours. i also have the timer in seconds right now and want it to change to minutes and hours once it gets to that time period. I have a start button and do not want to add a stop button or a reset button. Here is the swift code i have so far.

```
var timerCount = 0
var timerRunning = false
var timer = NSTimer()


@IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

func Counting(){

    timerCount += 1
    timerLabel.text = "\(timerCount)"

}

//Start button

@IBAction func startButton(sender: UIButton) {

    // If timer is not already running then start timer

    if timerRunning == false{
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("Counting"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        timerRunning = true

    }
```

Comment: You haven't a specific question so much as asked everyone to answer what is most likely your homework.  You need to ask specific questions, and discuss what you have tried and not.

Comment: You should use NSTimeInterval to measure time.  Just store the start date and display your start date timeIntervalSinceNow